# Getting Coordinates From Button Press Not Working

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am pretty new to Android Development, and I've tried to make a method in my Android Application, where you press the button and get coordinates (Longitude and Latitude). But the program stops working on the emulator when I press the button.

I am probably just doing something wrong here. Looking through the Callstack didn't help me. It was simply too cluttered with...a lot of useless information.

How do I fix this?

```
public void onLocateByGMapButtonClick() {
    LocationManager mloc = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mloc.getAllProviders();
    Location loc = new Location(providers.get(0));
    double loTude = loc.getLongitude();
    double laTude = loc.getLatitude();

    String newCoords = loTude + "," + laTude;
    location.setText(newCoords);
    Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(),"Location have been updated!",5);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you application is crashing is probably because you are receiving a `null pointer exception`.

You have to understand that a GPS fix is not an immediate process, it might take time and in this time you don't have a location to work on unless you use the `getLaskKnownLocation` method (which maybe return null as well).

So what you need to to is or use:

```
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

or implement a [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) that will fire as soon as a new location update arrives.

**Tutorial:**  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: But I don't want to track the user every time the location changes. I just want to get a set of coordinates for your current location when the button is pressed.

Comment: So create a LocationListener, wait until a new update arrives and fires it, and then just stop listen to update via: locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

Comment: Well..okay. Seems awfully complicated to just get a current set of coordinates. Thanks.

Comment: again you could use getLastKnownLocation(provider), but this might be not accurate and not as new as a new fix will be.